# cursor count is 0 in tablet but its 2 in phone

Tags: android, count, cursor

I am using `tablet (android version 4.1.1)` and `phone (android version 4.1.2)`.

I am trying to get the cursor count `onclick` but the results are different for tablet and phone.

Basically, the result is coming correct as expected with `phone` but not with `tablet`.

**My code:**

```
clickmaster.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    db = getDatabase(); //common method for open and accessing data

    String sql = "SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE source_id = ? AND cartname = ?";

    Cursor cur0 = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[]{sid,"MasterCart"});

    cur0.moveToFirst();

    System.out.println(cur0.getCount()); //Result 0 for tablet and 2 for phone.
   }
```

So in the above code, I am printing the `cur0.getCount()` and surprisingly its 0 for `tablet` but 2 for `phone`.

Why's that indifference?

Comment: phones are different means devices are using same databases with different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first uninstall app from both phone and tablet, and then run it again, and check,
in any of device you are accessing old database, clear DB from both phone and Tab first.